# Print Transpose of Vector or Print Dataframe without column names with default packages R 3.3.1

Tags: r, output, write.table

A vector with multiple objects is to be printed on the console with the names in a vertical table format.

Method-1: Print.dataframe the vector in a horizontal layout. However, the label appears as a column name.

Method-2: Write.table. But the text wrapped to the row names.

Please suggest if any other function is available. Please check a minimal example below for better understanding.

```
sv<-(1:4)
names(sv)<-c("Al", "BetaRay", "Gamma", "Zabracadabra")
sv
          Al      BetaRay        Gamma Zabracadabra 
           1            2            3            4 
print(data.frame(sv))
             sv
Al            1
BetaRay       2
Gamma         3
Zabracadabra  4

write.table(data.frame(sv), col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
Al 1
BetaRay 2
Gamma 3
Zabracadabra 4
```

Desired Output is:

```
Al            1
BetaRay       2
Gamma         3
Zabracadabra  4
```

Comment: Not really sure what you want, but try `unname(data.frame(sv))`

Answer (score 2):

one option is to use write.table. however, if you need columns aligned, then the width needs to be adjusted.

```
   library(gdata)
   df <- data.frame(c("Al", "BetaRay", "Gamma", "Zabracadabra"),c(1:4))
   write.fwf(df,quote=F,colnames = F)

   Al           1
   BetaRay      2
   Gamma        3
   Zabracadabra 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. This requires a new package gdata to be installed. Also, you're suggesting to create a new data frame with rownames also as a coloumn. However, the problem cited above is a mere example. The real problem is to print a named vector in a vertical layout with coloumns aligned in fixed width. Please let me know if you require the true case at hand.

Comment: Using the write.fwf suggested from gdata, I have used the following code.
main()
{
library(gdata)
df<-data.frame(names(sv), sv, row.names = NULL)
cat("\nSample Variance of each observation :")
write.fwf(df, quote=FALSE, colnames=FALSE)
}
Kindly suggest if this could be more concise and using the default packages in R.

Answer (score 0):

You are not completely clear on what you are trying to achieve here. From you desired output, I understand you are trying to write table to the console cleanly. Your approach is correct using the base R.

*data*

```
sv<-(1:4)
names(sv)<-c("Al", "BetaRay", "Gamma", "Zabracadabra")
```

---

```
# Method-1: Print.dataframe the vector in a horizontal layout.
# However, the label appears as a column name.

sv<-unname(data.frame(sv)) # as suggested by @DirtySockSniffer

dim(sv) 
[1] 4 1
```

Note: you have a 1 column data with 4 rows. What you are seeing is  rownames, 
I hope you are not mistaken by this when you say the " label appears as a      column name."

```
print(sv) # is exactly doing what you need

Al           1
BetaRay      2
Gamma        3
Zabracadabra 4


# Method-2: Write.table. But the text wrapped to the row names.
```

Note: The text is not wrapped into row names, it just appears so. write.table main purpose is to write a data frame to a file. I don't think it is recommended to print your data to console. However, when you specify separator, it can show some differentiation. But, it is not an efficient way.

```
write.table(sv, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t") # use a tab separator

   Al   1
BetaRay 2
Gamma   3
Zabracadabra    4

 # Other options require you to use some package to print cleanly to console.
 # install.packages("knitr") 
 require(knitr) 
 kable(sv)

|             | sv|
|:------------|--:|
|Al           |  1|
|BetaRay      |  2|
|Gamma        |  3|
|Zabracadabra |  4|
```

Datatable way ( more efficient in my opinion if you wish to do any further process on your dataframe) However, data table does not support row names by default numeric row names are generated. You are forced to make a column of `rn` if your data frame has row names. But, it writes cleanly to the console.

```
require(data.table) 

data.table(sv,keep.rownames = T)

             rn sv
1:           Al  1
2:      BetaRay  2
3:        Gamma  3
4: Zabracadabra  4
```

Answer (score 0):

When using data.frame(), you provide names for the *columns*, and enter data *by column*.  So, in the example below, Al=c(1) is the first column; it is named Al and it has one data value, 1. BetaRay=c(2) is the second column; it is named BetaRay and it has one data value, 2.

```
# This creates the dataframe named sv

sv <- data.frame(Al=c(1),BetaRay=c(2),Gamma=c(3),Zabracadabra=c(4))

# this prints sv

sv
  Al BetaRay Gamma Zabracadabra
1  1       2     3            4
 
# this prints the transpose of sv
 
t(sv)
             [,1]
Al              1
BetaRay         2
Gamma           3
Zabracadabra    4
 
# this prints the transpose of sv without column headers
 
unname(as.data.frame(t(sv)))
              
Al           1
BetaRay      2
Gamma        3
Zabracadabra 4
```